# Struts 2 iterator tag status index is not working

Tags: struts2

```
<s:iterator value="podTemplate.subTypeTemplates" status="subTemplate">
  <s:textfield id='subType_type_#subTemplate.index' key="subType" label="Name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

`#subTemplate.index` is not getting replaced by index. However if I am doing 
    `<s:property value="#subTemplate.index">` is working

Comment: Try subType_type_%{#subTemplate.index}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `id` attribute of textfield is of string type and string-type attributes are not interpreted as OGNL by default. As Steven said you have to force the interpretation by using `%{}` in your case `subType_type_%{#subTemplate.index}`.

Answer (score 0):

My iterator looks like this:

```
<s:iterator id="list" value="optionList" status="rowStatus" >
```

I tried:

```
<td>
    <input class="textInput required"type="text" name="optionList[${rowStatus.index}].option_id"/>
</td>
```

and it's the only one that worked.

All the following ones failed:

```
name="optionList[%{#rowStatus.index}].option_id"
name="%{optionList[#rowStatus.index].option_id}"
```

even

```
name="%{#rowStatus.index}"
```